# ValidationSummary mvc2 give vlidation result twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)%>

<%Html.ValidationSummary();  %>
```

I have added  ValidationSummary .At this time validation message appears twice in my form
.Any help?

Note that this form is rendered as a result of Ajax call.

Comment: Do you mean you have a validation summary twice or the validation error message is displayed next to the password and in the validation summary ?

Comment: validation error message appear twice ;one a the place of ValidationSummary and one a the place of  ValidationMessageFor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword, " ")%>
```

Solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

You could try excluding property errors from the summary:

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
```

Comment: true will hel to hide the validation message by  ValidationSummary.    i need validation summary

Comment: @user444569, no it will not tell to hide validation summary. It will tell to hide validation messages about model properties when you use it in conjunction with the `Html.ValidationMessageFor` helper to avoid getting duplicates which is what I thought your problem was. Apparently I am wrong.

Comment: Super tip, thanks much. I had the exact same issue and this solved it. I have model property errors that I want displayed and then I have custom validation whereby I invoke ModelState.AddModelError in my controller that I want displayed, but not together